# why is the default_scope being used for save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Added a default_scope to Spree::Product to sort the main page of a spree site, scope is `default_scope :include => :product_taxons, :order => "spree_product_taxons.position"`. This sorts it, but then when I try to update a product I'm getting the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'spree_product_taxons.position' in 'order clause': UPDATE `spree_products` SET `count_on_hand` = 100 WHERE `spree_products`.`id` = 108 ORDER BY spree_product_taxons.position`
```

First off, why is it trying to Order a update? 
and well, the field does exist

```
Spree::ProductTaxon
=> Spree::ProductTaxon(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, product_id: integer, taxon_id: integer, position: integer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field Exists in `spree_products_taxons`, but not in `spree_products`, hence the error. The `spree_products_taxons` `include` doesn't come into it in the update.